# "POST requires content-length error" occur when i am trying to call custom Rest API @HttpDelete Resource

Tags: rest-api

"POST requires content-length error" occur when i am trying to call custom Rest API @HttpDelete Resource ..

```
HttpRequest  req1=new HttpRequest();
req1.setMethod('POST');
    req1.setEndpoint('https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/MyPackageAC/ServerRestApi/0019000001N7LjKAAV?_HttpMethod=DELETE');  
req1.setHeader('Authorization','OAuth '+access_token);

HttpResponse res=p1.send(req1);
system.debug(res);
result=res.getBody();
```

---

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/ServerRestApi/*')
global class ServerResource
{

@HttpDelete
  global static void doDelete() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    String accountId=req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    Account account = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];
    delete account;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

POST requests require the `Content-Length` header to be set.

Salesforce does this automatically if you add a body to your `HttpRequest`. If you don't add a body then you need to manually set it to zero.

If you add the following to your callout you should be ok.

```
req.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');
```